# RCurl postForm issues with fieldnames with special characters

Tags: r, rcurl

How do I enclose a field name to postForm with RCurl when the form has fields like those below?

```
<input id="form:checkEstrato" type="checkbox" name="form:checkEstrato" checked="checked" />

<input id="form:checkArea" type="checkbox" name="form:checkArea" checked="checked" />
```

if I try something like

```
if(url.exists(url)) 
  results <- postForm(url,
           form:evento="35",
           form:area = "10")
```

I get

```
> if(url.exists(url)) 
+   results <- postForm(url,
+            form:evento="35",
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  results <- postForm(url,
           form:evento="
>            form:area = "10")
Error: unexpected ')' in "           form:area = "10")"
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact it was simple, although now I have to work it out why Rcurl doesn't get what I want.

At least to avoid de above error it as just a matter of enclosing the parameter name with quotes

```
if(url.exists(url)) 
  results <- postForm(url,
           'form:evento'="35",
           'form:area' = "10")
```

Now lets move ahead trying to understanding what is being sent to server and why its not working the way I expected.